# Salesforce Trigger help

Tags: apex, trigger

Hi I am trying to write a trigger on custom object ***Quote_Request__c*** - where I want to run the trigger when any field changes are performed on the Quote request records (except profile ids **id1** or **id2**)

```
trigger QuoteRequestChangeTrigger on Quote_Request__c (Before update) {
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objSchema = Quote_Request__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
Set<String> fields = objSchema.fields.getMap().keySet();

String[] changedFields  = new String[]{};
for(Quote_Request__c c; trigger.new;){
    for(string s: fields){
        if(c.get(s) != trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).get(s)){
            changedFields.add('Contact: ' + c.Id + ' - ' + s + ' - old:' + trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).get(s) + ' new:' + c.get(s));
        }
    }
}
```

The intent of the trigger is to update the rich text field (Via Process Builder) on quote request with changed field script that is defined on the trigger

```
changedFields.add('Contact: ' + c.Id + ' - ' + s + ' - old:' + trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).get(s) + ' new:' + c.get(s));
```

However, my trigger is coming with the error for the line 6:

```
 for(Quote_Request__c c; trigger.new;){
```

The error is: **Condition expression must of type Boolean: List**

Also how can I exclude profile ids ID1 or iD2 by triggering the changes?

What I am missing? Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm intrigued by your mention of Process Builder. From the sounds of it, you are using the trigger to set a value on the record which a Process Builder will then pick up and do further updates. Can you not do the Process Builder's work in the trigger? Process Builder has no concept of "before" or "after", it's all after, so that update will cause this trigger to fire again, and you're not checking whether this rich text field has already bee set.

Comment: @barrick - I learned it from the hard way. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for a `for` loop over an iterable (like sets and lists) is

`for(<Type> <loop variable name> :<iterable>)`

`for(Quote_Request__c c; trigger.new;)` is not proper syntax (those semicolons are incorrect).

What you're looking to write here is instead
`for(Quote_Request__c c :trigger.new)`
though I would recommend coming up with a more descriptive variable name. Something like `quoteReq` is superior to `c`. It may not be an issue with your trigger now (since it's short enough), but it's good practice.

As for making certain profiles not execute the actual work of the trigger, the simplest approach would be to simply `return;` if you detect one of your target profiles. The [Userinfo class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) can help you figure out information about the user who caused the trigger to fire.